# Using a single ethernet cable to extend network in secluded room

Tags: networking

**Goal:**
Great wireless signal and several available ethernet ports in my room. This would be achieved by using a single (straight through) ethernet cable, since said cable is already installed in my room.

**Problem:**
The router I have is across the house, therefore the signal strength in my room is weak and unstable (low bandwidth and high packet loss).

**What I have already tried:**
I have tried to use a wireless range extender, however the signal is still weak since it still has to pass through (although fewer) walls.

**Possible solution:**
After doing some research on my own, it appears that a router with both ethernet ports and wireless antennas is probably my best solution.

I'm currently interested in a router called "Edimax BR-6208AC V2".

Apparently, the router features an "Access Point Mode", which sounds like what I'm looking for:

> The device connects to an existing router via Ethernet cable and
> provides 2.4GHz and/or 5GHz Internet (wireless and Ethernet) access for
> your network devices.

**My question:**
I don't know if just connecting the aforementioned router to the main router would achieve my goal or if I would need to install a special (crossover) cable in my house.

Secondly, I would need it to be able to extend my current local network and not create a new, separate one.

Also, would this interfere with port forwarding, since the devices would technically be behind two routers (i. e. do I need to find out if the router supports port forwarding)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Home Ethernet - Connecting a second router to extend wifi](https://superuser.com/questions/1303596/home-ethernet-connecting-a-second-router-to-extend-wifi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect a good wireless router to your network and that will give you a good wireless signal. Get a regular wireless router including Ethernet ports.

Connect as folllows:

1. LAN Port on Wireless router to LAN port on your network - the Ethernet wire in your room.
2. Log into the Wireless Router and give it a Static IP on your network - so it does not get lost if you restart things. The Static IP will be an IP outside of the main Network DHCP scope. I usually use an IP address low in the subnet range assuming DHCP starts at 50 or greater.
3. Still in the Wireless Router setup, turn DHCP OFF because your main network hands out DHCP.

You may wish to restart the Wireless Router at this point.

Set up this way should not interfere with main Network port forwarding.

My view is that this is better overall than a simple Access Point. I do this and it works really well.

Comment: Not entirely agreeing with this answer, but +1 nevertheless because the most important stuff in it is correct. The router part is entirely bypassed if you only use the LAN ports and not the WAN port. DHCP should indeed be turned off, otherwise you have 2 DHCP servers on the network, but for the rest it is more out of management than anything else.

Comment: I understand but I always found it easier as I described it because (for me) the added router part has not been necessary in a home environment. Of course there is more than one way to do things. Thanks.

Comment: Might want to add "put the static ip of the 2nd router" outside of the first ones DHCP range.

Comment: Good point - done.

Comment: Thanks for your update.